# Autobahn python : ImportError: No module named wamp1

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am new to python and want to use autobahn test suite for websocket testing. Using following instructions to setup the suite:

```
git clone git://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnTestSuite.git

cd AutobahnTestSuite
git checkout v0.6.1
cd autobahntestsuite
python setup.py install
```

To get the manual of wstest, I entered `wstest --help` but it threw this error:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wstest", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('autobahntestsuite==0.6.1', 'console_scripts', 'wstest')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2672, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2351, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import wstest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/wstest.py", line 40, in <module>
    import wamptestee
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/wamptestee.py", line 19, in <module>
    from autobahn.wamp1 import protocol as wamp
**ImportError: No module named wamp1**
```

Please assist me to remove above error from my Ubuntu linux box.

Comment: The version that you require is available [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahntestsuite/0.6.1) as well. See if `pip install autobahntestsuite` works.

Comment: Animesh : I tried using pip tool also, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by using Autobahn previous version. This issue resolved after installing Autobahn test suite latest version v0.7.1.